# Web page does not open

Tags: eclipse, spring

```
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer property decoder has been initialized.
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:testispring' did not find a matching property.
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Aineistopankki01' did not find a matching property.
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1234 ms
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: SpringSource tc Server/6.0.20.C
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/administrator/springsource/tc-server-6.0.20.C/wtpwebapps/Aineistopankki01/WEB-INF/lib/javax.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [/home/administrator/springsource/tc-server-6.0.20.C/wtpwebapps/Aineistopankki01/]
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive insight.war
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Sep 20 11:22:46 EEST 2010]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/mvc-config.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/app-config-tomcat.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/springsource/insight/dashboard/app-config-base.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2898b13b: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,localeResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver#0,tilesConfigurer,jsonView,traces/window/json,traces/trace/json,resources/resource/leadingAverage/json,resources/resource/histogram/json,resources/resources/json,traces/last/xstream,freemarkerConfig,tracesController,traceRepoInterceptAttacher,applicationsController,homeController,sorter,configController,resourcesController,resourceSummaryFactory,executorTraceCreator,insightVersionNumber,insightApplication,memoryMetricDataRepo,staticMetricRepo,memoryResourceRepoImpl,memoryTraceRepo,traceFilterListFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,conversionService,endPointAnalysisTraceListener,traceListenerList,traceCreatingExecutor,com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.YamlInsightConfigFactoryBean#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.YamlInsightConfigFactoryBean - Reading Spring Insight config: /home/administrator/springsource/tc-server-6.0.20.C/conf/spring-insight.yml
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/windows/{start}/{end:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/lastTraces/{application}/{end}/{count}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/lastTraces/{application}/{end}/{count}.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/lastTraces/{application}/{end}/{count}/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/frames/{frameId}/operation] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/frames/{frameId}/operation.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/frames/{frameId}/operation/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@6b4d6015]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces/{application:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints/{application:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints/{application}/{resource:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@500b2175]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Root mapping to handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.HomeController@5b082d45]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@447cc9c9]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@447cc9c9]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@447cc9c9]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@447cc9c9]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/histogram] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/histogram.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/histogram/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/leadingAverage] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/leadingAverage.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/leadingAverage/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/traces/{start}/{end}/{min}/{max:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@2b5d925b]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer - TilesConfigurer: adding definitions [/WEB-INF/**/tiles*.xml]
WARN : org.apache.tiles.context.ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory - Cannot find TilesRequestContextFactory class org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer - ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization completed in 3193 ms
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:49 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 20, 2010 11:22:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5642 ms
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using the right URL? This log shows the server *has* started up on port 8080

Comment: Yes. It should also be using the right port.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other servelet paths defined in @RequestMapping anottation?
OR have you defined an welcome-file-list:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Check the ViewResolver to check if you are mapping the files to the right path.